# Unit Testing Postgres Database with Maven

Tags: sql, eclipse, unit-testing, maven, dbunit

First let me explain what I am doing:

Creating a Java project in Eclipse (JUNO) to unit test SQL for a Postgres database.

Using Maven2 as the build tool.  I have DBUnit, and SQL maven plugins.

The goal is to drop the schema and rebuild the tables and load some data in the tables.

I've tested the SQL so I know it works. I have tested the connections so I know the URL is right.

Now onto my problem.  I am new to Maven for unit testing SQL.  I have tried to follow most of the online documentation.   I have created my pom from the examples.   While the Java code compiles, the build blows by the SQL work in the pom.xml file.    Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.premierinc.esd</groupId>
<artifactId>sqlunittest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>sqlunittest</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <junit.version>3.8.1</junit.version>
    <maven.compiler.plugin.version>2.5.1</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
    <sql.maven.plugin.version>1.5</sql.maven.plugin.version>
    <postgresql.jdbc.version>9.1-901.jdbc4</postgresql.jdbc.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgresql.jdbc.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${sql.maven.plugin.version}</version>

                <dependencies>
                    <!-- specify the dependent jdbc driver here -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>${postgresql.jdbc.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <!-- common configuration shared by all executions -->
                <configuration>
                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432:testdb</url>
                    <username>postgres</username>
                    <password>root</password>
                    <!-- You can comment out username/password configurations and have 
                        maven to look them up in your settings.xml using ${settingsKey} -->
                    <settingsKey>sensibleKey</settingsKey>
                    <!--all executions are ignored if -Dmaven.test.skip=true -->
                    <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                </configuration>


                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>drop-schema-before-test-if-any</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- need another database to drop the targeted one -->
                            <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432:postgres</url>
                            <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                            <sqlCommand>DROP SCHEMA chipen CASCADE</sqlCommand>
                            <!-- ignore error when database is not available -->
                            <onError>continue</onError>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>


                    <execution>
                        <id>create-schema</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                            <srcFiles>
                                <srcFile>src/main/sql/CHI-PEN-schema.sql</srcFile>
                            </srcFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>dbunit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-3</version>


                <dependencies>
                    <!-- specify the dependent jdbc driver here -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>${postgresql.jdbc.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <!-- common configuration shared by all executions -->
                <configuration>
                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432:testdb</url>
                    <username>postgres</username>
                    <password>root</password>
                    <!-- You can comment out username/password configurations and have 
                        maven to look them up in your settings.xml using ${settingsKey} -->
                    <settingsKey>sensibleKey</settingsKey>
                    <!--all executions are ignored if -Dmaven.test.skip=true -->
                    <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                </configuration>

                <executions>

                    <execution>

                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>operation</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <!-- specific configurations -->
                        <configuration>
                            <type>CLEAN_INSERT</type>
                            <src>src/test/data/testdb_chipen_data.xml</src>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Any suggestions or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say blows by the SQL, do you mean that the SQL is not executed?

Comment: First why are you defining the defaults (repositories) in your pom? Furthermore are you really using Maven 2 on command line? In Juno you are using Maven 3 already so best is to use Maven 3 on command line as well as in Eclipse Juno.

Comment: You might find this new plugin useful: https://github.com/adrianboimvaser/postgresql-maven-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add the pom of your post here in corrected form. I have removed in particular the repository definition, cause they are the defaults in Maven so convention over configurations mean to define only what is really needed to define.
Furthermore i have removed the **pluginManagement** tags, cause this means not to really execute the things it means define things. To be more accurate [pluginManagement](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) is intended to define the versions of plugins but usually not the configuration. This is usually used in parent pom's:

```
<project ...>
  ..
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
           Plugin groupId, artifactId, version
        </plugin>
        .
      </plugin>
    </pluginManagement>
    ..
</project>
```

Let us get back to your pom. The follow should run:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.premierinc.esd</groupId>
<artifactId>sqlunittest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>sqlunittest</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <junit.version>3.8.1</junit.version>
    <maven.compiler.plugin.version>2.5.1</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
    <sql.maven.plugin.version>1.5</sql.maven.plugin.version>
    <postgresql.jdbc.version>9.1-901.jdbc4</postgresql.jdbc.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgresql.jdbc.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${sql.maven.plugin.version}</version>

                <dependencies>
                    <!-- specify the dependent jdbc driver here -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>${postgresql.jdbc.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <!-- common configuration shared by all executions -->
                <configuration>
                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432:testdb</url>
                    <username>postgres</username>
                    <password>root</password>
                    <!-- You can comment out username/password configurations and have 
                        maven to look them up in your settings.xml using ${settingsKey} -->
                    <settingsKey>sensibleKey</settingsKey>
                    <!--all executions are ignored if -Dmaven.test.skip=true -->
                    <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>drop-schema-before-test-if-any</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- need another database to drop the targeted one -->
                            <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432:postgres</url>
                            <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                            <sqlCommand>DROP SCHEMA chipen CASCADE</sqlCommand>
                            <!-- ignore error when database is not available -->
                            <onError>continue</onError>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>


                    <execution>
                        <id>create-schema</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                            <srcFiles>
                                <srcFile>src/main/sql/CHI-PEN-schema.sql</srcFile>
                            </srcFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>dbunit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-3</version>


                <dependencies>
                    <!-- specify the dependent jdbc driver here -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>${postgresql.jdbc.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <!-- common configuration shared by all executions -->
                <configuration>
                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432:testdb</url>
                    <username>postgres</username>
                    <password>root</password>
                    <!-- You can comment out username/password configurations and have 
                        maven to look them up in your settings.xml using ${settingsKey} -->
                    <settingsKey>sensibleKey</settingsKey>
                    <!--all executions are ignored if -Dmaven.test.skip=true -->
                    <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                </configuration>

                <executions>

                    <execution>

                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>operation</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <!-- specific configurations -->
                        <configuration>
                            <type>CLEAN_INSERT</type>
                            <src>src/test/data/testdb_chipen_data.xml</src>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

Apart from the above a thing like this are integration tests and **not** unit tests but this is a different question/discussion.

Comment: Okay.  Thank you everyone from you suggestions and advice.  I really do appreciate it.  I have removed the plugin management element along with the local repository.  This got the SQL scripts to execute.

Comment: Is there any good reason why you should use the dbunit-maven-plugin in addition to the sql-maven-plugin instead of just using the sql-maven-plugin as done in [this example](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/examples/execute.html)?